# How to change bounding boxes position according to image resize?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr, bounding-box

I changed and normalize a binary image from `[239, 397]` to `[128, 128]` using `processLetter` function as I found [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/63220-character-size-normalisation?focused=7748171&tab=function). The image contained Arabic letters bounded by boxes in ground truth values. When I change the size, I must change the bounding boxes consequently. I wrote this code and the bounding boxes are not adjusted accordingly to the original image which you can find here:

[image: Original image]

I'm digging hard to fix this problem, but I'm stuck and fail. I need your help.

Simple code is going here:

```
%% clean workspace
clear;
clc;
%% Read the image
im_origin = imread('C:\Users\asa\Desktop\im_origin.bmp');
% Get the original image size
[w1,h1,c1] = size(im_origin)
% function to resize the image size into [128 128]
im_resized = processLetter(im_origin);
[w2,h2,c2]= size(im_resized);
%% Read Bound box values in form [ax ay w h]
GTBoxes = [263 74   68 78;
            161 74  101 78;
            61  74  99  78];
[rowGT colGT] = size(GTBoxes);
%% Resize bounding box
% Get scale from division of height of the resized image(h2) over the 
% original image(h1)
scale = h2/h1;
BBresized = bboxresize(GTBoxes,scale);
imshow(im_resized);
hold on;
%% Draw bounding boxes around the letters
 for i=1:rowGT
  rectangle('Position',BBresized(i,:),'EdgeColor','y');
  pause(2);
 end
```

This is the image after resizing:

[image: 3]

And, here is the resized image with the corresponding (wrong) bounding boxes.

[image]

I appreciate any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two issues here:

1. `[w1, h1, c1] = size(im_origin)` is wrong, it's `[h, w, c]`.
2. You have different scaling factors for width and height.

I reworked your example using simple [`imresize`](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html), and manually scaling, since I only have Octave rght now for testing (below code also works in MATLAB Online). That `processLetter` function also seems to crop the text from the image!? So, you'd need to make sure to correct for that also (outside the scope of my answer)!

```matlab
% Read original image, get size
im_origin = imread('Dmkoh.png');
[h1, w1, c1] = size(im_origin)

% Set up original bounding boxes, get size
GTBoxes = [263 74  68 78;
           161 74 101 78;
            61 74  99 78]
[rowGT, colGT] = size(GTBoxes);

% Plot original image with bounding boxes
figure(1);
imshow(im_origin);
hold on;
for i = 1:rowGT
  rectangle('Position', GTBoxes(i, :), 'EdgeColor', 'y');
end
hold off;

% Resize image (using imresize here), get size
im_resized = imresize(im_origin, [128, 128]);
[h2, w2, c2] = size(im_resized)

% Resize bounding boxes (using simple scaling)
BBresized = GTBoxes;
BBresized(:, [1, 3]) = BBresized(:, [1, 3]) * w2/w1;
BBresized(:, [2, 4]) = BBresized(:, [2, 4]) * h2/h1;

% Plot resized image with bounding boxes
figure(2);
imshow(im_resized);
hold on;
for i = 1:rowGT
  rectangle('Position', BBresized(i, :), 'EdgeColor', 'y');
end
hold off;
```

Original:

[image: Original]

Resized:

[image: Resized]

Comment: There are differences between the two resize functions processLetter and imresize.

Comment: Thank you, for your correction statement [w,h,c] to [h,w,c].